# Exercise to isolate the leg stability muscles used when walking backwards

Tags: muscle-recovery

Particularly as you place the ball of your foot down and transfer weight onto it.

From *this* image I believe it's #3, and #18-20. These correspond with Sartorius, Gracilis, Adductor Longus, and Pectineus, respectively.

[image: Leg muscles]

They've become deactivated after my [PCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_cruciate_ligament) tear, and due to 'not having faith in them' I've developed bad form in my one-leg squats.

Preferably something that I can do at home. I'm attempting some sit-ups/leg-lifts next, but I'd really like to pack on improve my strength in this area.

Answer (score 3):

[brianmac.co.uk](http://www.brianmac.co.uk/glutes.htm#ref) said that *LIEBENSON, C (2006) Rehabilitation of the Spine: A Practitioner’s Manual* says "if a lack of coordination is seen when walking backwards it indicates the gluteus maximus is weak."

The muscles that let me walk backwards without all kinds of twisting were the gluteus minimus (activated by the [hip hitch](http://www.sportsinjurybulletin.com/archive/gluteus-exercise.html)) and the gluteus medius. Trouble in the single-leg squat [indicates](http://www.ptonthenet.com/blog/the-inner-unit/gluteus-medius-an-integral-part-of-foot-function-260) issues with the gluteus medius. There are three exercises listed on that page, of which the wall press was the best for helping me feel the muscle.

Comment: This answer is underrated, thanks for the detailed reply +Noumenon.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse lunges, which you can scale up with either weights at your side, or a barbell in either the front rack or backsquat position, or even overhead if you want to get really spicy?

Offered with NO knowledge of what happens during or after a PCL tear, so please take grains of salt as needed. :D